# UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id: 'in.juspay.hypersdk-asset', version: '1.0.3',

Tags: android

Any idea about Juspay Android Hyper SDK plugin for newer Android Studio plugin support?

Original & existing working code:

```
def juspayHyperSDKVersion = '1.0.3'
 classpath "in.juspay:hypersdk-asset-plugin:$juspayHyperSDKVersion"
```

Trying new code

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.4.2' apply false
    
    id 'in.juspay.hypersdk-asset' version '1.0.3' apply false

}
```